# Paypal echeck IPN callback cancelling orders

Tags: paypal, magento-1.6

I have an issue with a store we look after. Magento version 1.6.2.0

Almost immediately after an order is placed using a PayPal echeck, we receive an IPN callback cancelling the order. This in turn cancels the order, and its items. 6 days later we receive notification that the payment is complete and the order is moved to the processing, then complete state.

Unfortunately at this stage we have orders that are set to complete, with cancelled line items. Is this normal Magento/PayPal behaviour or is it a bug in the native PayPal module? Could it possibly be an incorrect setting in the PayPal account itself? It seems strange to me that PayPal would send a cancellation notification back so soon after the order is placed.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not a default behavior**. The Paypal IPN should advance status forward into the `Pending Paypal` status. If this status is not available, the results may be unpredictable. I would do the following:

- Check the custom statuses (Admin > System > Order Statuses) and ensure that status for `pending_paypal` is there and that its state is set to Pending
- Check your Paypal Standard / Express settings and make sure that orders are coming in status Pending.
- [Check your IPN endpoint](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/paypal_standard_payments_setup_with_ipn) - after 1.4.0.1 it should be http://www.yoursite.com/paypal/ipn/
- [File a ticket with Paypal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/ask/session/L3RpbWUvMTM3MDM1Nzc4My9zaWQvaipQNjFWcmw=) or tweet them (https://twitter.com/PayPal_MTS) to ask them to delay the IPN response by 3-5 minutes (I've had them do this in the past for debugging purposes) to account for a race condition that may be interfering with the order payment / place process

After you've checked all of the above, I would assume a code issue. Disable local modules and [follow the standard debugging process](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/).

Comment: Cheers philwinkle. Having checked the Order Status I saw that it had no State Code set. I have set it to Pending as you suggested and fingers crossed that will sort the issue. If not i'll go through your other suggestions.